# How to skip character columns when summarise in R?

Tags: r

I have a following problem. I want to compute a mean of two datasets. See bellow:

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012),
                  month = c("01", "02", "03"),
                  col1 = c(4, 3, 2),
                  col2 = c(23, 41, 32)
)


df2 <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012),
                  month = c("01", "02", "03"),
                  col1 = c(40, 30, 20),
                  col2 = c(13, 11, 12)
)
```

I tried this:

```
df_together <- bind_rows(df1 %>% add_rownames(), 
                       df2 %>% add_rownames()) %>% 
  # evaluate following calls for each value in the rowname column
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  # mean
  summarise_all(mean)
```

which gives me:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  rowname  year month  col1  col2
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1        2010    NA  22      18
2 2        2011    NA  16.5    26
3 3        2012    NA  11      22
```

Is there a way, how to "skip" characters in column `month`? I tried to add `select_if(is.numeric)`, but it did not work to me.

Desired output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  rowname  year month  col1  col2
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1        2010    01  22      18
2 2        2011    02  16.5    26
3 3        2012    03  11      22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
   group_by(year, month) %>%
   summarize(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop")
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   year month  col1  col2
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2010 01     22      18
2  2011 02     16.5    26
3  2012 03     11      22
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the additional grouping variables:

```
group_by(rowname, year, month) %>% ....
```

I also recommend you ending the code chunk with

```
... %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do you recommend to end with `%>% as.data.frame()` ?

Comment: If you look at the object class you just created when playing the "group_by" method, you will see that it is ["tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"]. This arrangement of classes could generate problems later if you keep making changes to the database. To avoid possible latter issues, I always redefine the object class with "%>% as.data.frame()" at the end of the code chunk.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you